# Swift UI Test fails on iphone4s simulator works well with others

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ui-testing, nsunknownkeyexception

I have a login screen in my app then after login view being dismissed a tabbar appears.

App itself works well in all devices/simulators. UI test works in all simulators except iphone 4s.

I think the reason is after login , it takes way too longer to login screen to disappear. So when I try to access tabbar, it throws an exception.

I tried

```
let tabBarsQuery = app.tabBars
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
expectationForPredicate(predicate, evaluatedWithObject: tabBarsQuery, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(15, handler: nil)
```

I get following error

```
failed: caught "NSUnknownKeyException", "[<XCUIElementQuery 0x7e080d40> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key exists."
```

Why expectation is not working? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did all the devices you used for testing have the exact same iOS firmware?

Comment: I set the all simulators to 9.2 and now it is happening in all of them.

Comment: when I remove `predicate` it works for all of them besides 4s though

Answer (score 0):

So the issue with this seems to be that for whatever reason, the .exists property does not exist for a collection of XCUIElementQueries. In your example, you could not do `app.tabBars.exists`. However, you can change your predicate to be:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "count > 0")
```

And that should work.